# Get number of objects by name Corona SDK

Tags: sdk, count, coronasdk

I'm trying to see if it's possible to get all the objects with the same name. I'm using the following code to load a bunch of circles on the screen. They all have the same

```
local myCircle = display.newCircle(30+(yCount*20), 220+(yCount*10), 8)
myCircle.name = "peg"
```

I would imagine there is a way to do this but I'm not sure where to even look for such a thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a circle array

```
array = {}
```

Then when you create a single circle, you should add that circle to the array

```
array[#array+1] = myCircle
```

Now here is the find function by spesific name

```
local function findByName( name )
    local resultArray = {}
    for i=1, #array do
        if array[i].name == name then
             resultArray[#resultArray+1] = array[i]
        end
    end
    return resultArray
end
```

So, at the end, when you call

```
local tempArray = findByName( "peg" )
```

you'll get circles named "peg" in tempArray